# Input/Output scanset in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    char str[50]={'\0'};
    scanf("%[A-Z]s",str);  
    printf("%s",str);        
    return 0;
}
```

1)
Input:

> helloWORLD

output:

> 

2)
Input:

> HELLoworlD

output:

> HELL

In output 1, i expected the output as "WORLD" but it didnt give any outout.
From output 2, i understood that this is working only if the first few characters are in upper case.

Can you please explain how it actually works?

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()`.  There's practically no way to tell whether or not the `s` after the upper-case characters is read.  If you thought that the `s` was part of the scanset, please go back and re-read the manual page — it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
scanf("%[A-Z]s",str);
```

It takes input as long as you enter upper-case letters.
And since you set all the array to `'\0'`, `printf()` will stop printing when it meets one.

Therefore, the first input is blank, and the second is printing until the end of the upper-case string.

Comment: The `%[A-Z]` conversion specification will insert a null at the end of the string, so the initialization of string doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

#### Interpretation of scansets

When it is given `helloWORLD`, the conversion specification `%[A-Z]` fails immediately because the `h` is not an upper-case letter.  Therefore, `scanf()` returns 0, indicating that it did not successfully convert anything.  If you tested the return value, you'd know that.

When it is given `HELLoworlD`, the scanset matches the `HELL` and stops at the first `o`.  The format string also attempts to match a literal `s`, but there's no way for `scanf()` to report that it fails to match that after matching `HELL`.

---

#### Buffer overflow

Note that `%[A-Z]` is in general dangerous (as is `%s`) because there is no constraint on the number of characters read.  If you have:

```
char str[50];
```

then you should use:

```
if (scanf("%49[A-Z]", str) != 1)
    ...some problem in the scan...
```

Also note that there is a 'difference by one' between the declared length of `str` and the number in the format string.  This is awkward; there's no way to provide that number as an argument to `scanf()` separate from the format string (unlike `printf()`), so you may end up creating the format string on the fly:

```
int scan_upper(char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char format[16];
    if (buflen < 2)
        return EOF;  // Or other error indication
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%zu[A-Z]", buflen-1);  // Check this too!?
    return scanf(format, buffer);
}
```