# Unexpected output of scansets in C

Tags: c, set

as expected this prog. should accept a number until it encounters a 4 but it gives some garbage value. why?

```
int main(void)
{

    int a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%[^4]d", &a);

    printf("You entered: %d\n", a);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note that the format will never read the `d` that is requested because if there is a `d` in the data, it will be read as part of the character string matched by the scan set (because `d` is not a digit `4`).  You also need to realize that scan sets are for character strings, not for integers — that's why the `d` is just a literal character in the format string and not part of a conversion specification.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know scansets are meant to be used with strings (which makes the `d` not act as an integer placeholder specification). One way to write it is to read the input into a string and then parse it:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    char b[255];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%254[^4]", &b);

    a = atoi(b);
    printf("You entered: %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm keeping the modified code to a minimum, you'd definitely need some extra checks for input sanity.

To clarify: The `254` prefix limits the amount of data that `scanf` will capture, so as to not exceed the size of the buffer (strings are terminated with an extra null character, so the read length must be smaller than the actual size)<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481367/input-output-scanset-in-c#answer-17482214)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

The [scanset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) working with only characters.

Here is my sample code. (but, I don't know what you really want.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char buffer[128];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%[^4]s", buffer);

    printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is,

```
Enter a number: 12345678
You entered: 123
```

Additionally, if you want integer value, use [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html).

Comment: Note that the `s` is a literal `s`, not part of the scan set conversion specification.  See also my comment to the question, referring to the `d` in the question.  But you're right that the scan set is for strings, not for integers, but the scan set doesn't include the `s`.